# Regex matching very slow

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I am trying to parse a PDF to extract the text from it (please don't suggest any libraries to do this, as this is part of learning the format).
I have already handled deflating it to put it in the alphanumeric format. I now need to extract the text from the text blocks.
So, my current pattern is `BT.*?\((.*?)\).*?ET` (with DOTMATCHALL set) to match something like:

```
BT
   /F13 12 Tf
   288 720 Td
   (ABC) Tj
ET
```

The only bit I want is the text ABC in the brackets.
The above is only formatted like that to make it clear to see. In the deflated text it may be all in one line, it may not be. There is no gurantee that the BT/ET will be at the start of a line. There may be spaces and text before/after the bracketed section, there may not be. There will however, be only one bracketed section per BT/ET block.

The above pattern works, but is really slow, I assume it is because the regex library is failing to match the pattern that matches the text between BT and the (ABC) many times.
The regex is pre-compiled in an attempt to speed it up, but it seems negligible.

How may I speed this up?

Comment: I think your regex is formatted incorrectly. You might try putting it in backticks (\`foo\`) and see if displays correctly.

Comment: Also what language are you using? Regex has many variants.

Comment: It is backticked. The parser is python's implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one without regex. simple string parsing using Python internals.

```
>>> xtract="""
... BT
...    /F13 12 Tf
...    288 720 Td
...    (ABC) Tj
... ET
...
... """
>>> for chunk in xtract.split("ET"):
...     if "BT" in chunk:
...         for brace in chunk.split(")"):
...             if "(" in brace:
...                  print brace[brace.find("(")+1:]
...
ABC
```

Comment: Ultimately, this is the only answer here that works at a sensible speed.

Answer (score 4):

How many of these blocks might appear in a document?

Often slow Regex execution is the result of catastrophic backtracking, as described here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

I don't know what regex technology you're using, but you could try to use lookaround assertions, as described here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

These allow you to first just match what you want, `ABC` inside parentheses, and then validate that it is preceded by some value and followed by some other value.

Comment: Large numbers of blocks, all text sits inside one, but you may get several paragraphs worth inside on block.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the regex is correct and pulls out ABC as a match? What language's regex engine is this? Using my regular expression debugger shows that:

`"BT.*?((.*?)).*?ET"` doesn't pull out ABC and in fact must find the string 'ET' then backtrack back to find everything else.

`"BT.*?\\((.*?)\\).*?ET"` works as expected with a single pass left to right.

Comment: The engine is python's. I was testing using one of the online tools, which reported it pulling out in the correct block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just parse the PDF with a regex to extract the text. In most cases the text in inside compressed binary blobs or encoded. A PDF with the text shown like this is very much the exception.

Comment: Did you not see that I mentioned that I had already deflated the blob? The text excerpt in the question is the actual PDF format (take a look at the specification if you don't believe me)

Comment: Yes, but deflating it only works if the text is WinANSI encoded and not subsetted. The values in the TJ command are index values which happen to be the same as the text values only if it is WinANSI encoded and not subsetted. Otherwise they need to be converted using the embedded CMAP or the tables in Appendix D of the PDF Reference.

Comment: Heh, take a look at the PDF spec indeed. Perhaps don't be so quick to down vote in the future.

Comment: I have put a longer and more detailed explanation about the Tj command on our blog at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/27187/Understanding-the-PDF-file-format-text-streams

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough info for a definite answer--or maybe you're assuming we know more about PDF than you do.  Are there always parenthesized chunks inside these `BT...ET` sections?  Is there always only one of them?  Is the `BT` or `ET` always at the beginning of a line?  If so, I would suggest

```
(?m)^BT[^()]*\((.*?)\)[^()]*?^ET
```

If I knew how PDF represented literal parentheses, I could probably come up with something more efficient.

EDIT: According to the PDF spec, literal parentheses have to be escaped with a backslash, and there are a bunch of other backslash-escape sequences.  So try this:

```
(?s)\bBT\b[^()]*\(((?:[^()\\]*(?:\\.[^()\\]*)*))\)
```

This part--`[^()\\]*(?:\\.[^()\\]*)*`--matches a block of text which may contain escaped characters (including parens), but not unescaped parens.  I know it looks ugly, but it's the most efficient way, since Python doesn't support atomic groups or possessive quantifiers.

`(?s)` allows `.` to match newlines, and `\bBT\b` makes sure the `BT` isn't part of a longer "word".  I'm reasonably confident that this is all I need to match all of the actual text content, so I don't bother matching the stuff after the closing paren.

Comment: Parentheses are represented as the ascii character. It is just like a text stream, just with some special control characters. I have put some information about PDF in the question, just beneath the example section I am looking for.

Comment: Hmm. Gskinner's online tester is happy with that, but python is reporting a 'raise error, v # invalid expression' 'sre_constants.error@ unexpected end of regular expression', yet it looks like all brackets/parentheses are matched.

Comment: It works for me in this python regex tester: http://re.dabase.com/webre.py?input=BT%0D%0A+++%2FF13+12+Tf%0D%0A+++288+720+Td%0D%0A+++%28ABC%29+Tj%0D%0AET&regex=%28%3Fs%29\bBT\b[^%28%29]*\%28%28%28%3F%3A[^%28%29\\]*%28%3F%3A\\.[^%28%29\\]*%29*%29%29\%29

Answer (score 0):

Since there will be only one bracketed expression between a `BT` and an `ET`, you could try the following regular expression for speed:

```
r"(?s)\bBT\b[^(]*\(([^)]*)\).*?\bET\b"
```

Comment: Intriguingly, this seems to find only one the second block BT/ET block.

Comment: If you use the `.search` method of the compiled regular expression, then this will find a single match; if you use `.finditer`, you'll get all matches. Unless I misunderstood your comment.